# Google Play 64 Bit Compliance

Tags: java, android, google-play, apk, buildbox

I have a game developed by Buildbox2. As BB states their latest version has 64 bit support.

https://www.buildbox.com/forum/index.php?threads/buildbox-2-3-8-2509-beta.17155/

I downloaded latest BB2 and export my game to Android.

Then I **Analyze APK**

As you see in the picture:

[image: so files]

There are two .so files in lib folder. I am wondering "Does my app support 64 bit for Google Play?"

What do you think?

How can I make it 64 bit compliant?

Comment: `I am wondering "Does my app support 64 bit for Google Play?"` have you tried submitting the APK and seeing what Google says?

Comment: No, submitting will take time. Before submitting I decided to ask to StackOverflow.

Comment: Submitting is just a few seconds when you stick with the Alpha/Beta channel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you find out '.so' files in the arm64-v8a or x86_64 folder, It does mean that this app supports 64 bit. You also could find your own answer by reading the official doc of Google.

[ApK analyzer](https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/64-bit#apk-analyzer)

Comment: my application doesn't conatin any '.so' files